# In Android Studio, running 64 bit windows, should I set virtual devices in the AVD to 86x64 or 86?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I figured since my OS is 64 bit then I should pick 86x64, but it seems to not run the app correctly.

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: No error. The java time picker didnt work right though. I think I just need to download a 64 bit jdk and point to it from file->project structure. The app works fine after switching the emulator to 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use android studio 2.0  By default, this includes the x86 system image that you need for the emulator.

Comment: What do I need to do in order for a 64 bit virtual device to work properly? I have android studio 1.4 if it matters. I did java -version in the studio and it does indeed say its a 32 bit VM. How do I change it to 64 bit? If I click Help->About it shows JVM:64 bit server

Comment: do you check this:  for accelerated emulator: 64-bit operating system and Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality    Also you can check in your AndroidSDKmanager if you have he x86 Atom System Images and the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager Driver.

Comment: I think I can go to file->project structure, and point to a 64 bit jdk. This should fix, I will see.

Comment: Your answer got me on the right track to solving the issue. I had to install version 12 of Google APIs 86x64/x86 system image(in the SDK manager). I previously had version 7. So it did indeed have to do with the system image. The emulator runs lightning quick now and does not require double clicks anymore. This was wreaking havoc on the timePickerDialog. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The x64 image specifies the emulator type that you are about to run, which in this case means it will run the 64bit android OS in the virtual device. This has nothing to do with your PC architecture but I doubt you will be able to run a 64bit android virtual device on a x86 machine.

P.S: Did you mean AVD instead of AMD?

Comment: Oh My. Yes, I meant AVD.

Comment: If I type java -version in the studio, it says I am using a 32 bit JVM. Does this mean the JVM on my PC is 32 bit? So I just need to change it to 64? My app is running fine after switching the virtual device to 32 bit, but I just want to know how I can get a 64 bit device to function if I want to.

Comment: If your JDK is 32bit then the JVM should be 32bit. I haven't developed in the 32 bit environment much so I can't be sure of your second question, but installing a 64 bit JDK should work.

Comment: I solved the issue. I had to upgrade the Google APIs Atom_64 system image from version 7 to version 12. I did not give enough information in original question. The emulator was making me double click, and it was wreaking havoc on the timePickerDialog. Before solving the issue, I did change my SDK and JVM to 64 bit but it had no effect. Your recent comment has helped in my understanding of these basic ideas though, so thanks.